# ASP.NET Core 2.1 - Memory cache - value set in middleware cannot be accessed by controller

Tags: c#, memorycache

I am using IMemoryCache in Asp.Net Core 2.1 Webapi project to temporarily store some data received from RabbitMq channel. I have a channel listener in a customised middleware. But when I try to access the data in the cache from controller, there is no data in it. I am using Autofac as my DI framework.

If I set a value to memory cache in a controller, I can get it from other classes, such as a service (also registered in Autofac DI) associated with this controller.

My implementation is as follow:

1. In Startup.cs, I have

`services.AddMemoryCache();`

and then use the middleware as

```
app.UseMiddleware<RabbitMqConsumerMiddleware>();
app.UseCors("default")
    .UseAuthentication()
    .UseMvc();`
```

My Autofac registration is as follow:

Here is my Autofac registration

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
RabbitMqConfiguration rabbitMqConfiguration = new RabbitMqConfiguration();
        Configuration.GetSection("RabbitMq").Bind(rabbitMqConfiguration);
        services.AddSingleton(rabbitMqConfiguration);

        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddJsonFormatters()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()
            .AddControllersAsServices()
            .AddApiExplorer();

        services.AddRabbitMq(rabbitMqConfiguration);
        services.AddMemoryCache();


        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.Populate(services);
        IContainer container = builder.Build();
        return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
    }
```

2. In the middleware, I have

   ```
   public RabbitMqConsumerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IMemoryCache memoryCache, RabbitMqConfiguration configuration, IModel messageBodyReceiverChannel)
   {
       _next = next;
       _memoryCache = memoryCache;
       _configuration = configuration;
       _messageBodyReceiverChannel = messageBodyReceiverChannel;
   }

   public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
   {
       bool isMessageBodyReceiverConsumerExist = _memoryCache.TryGetValue("message-body-receiver-consumer", out EventingBasicConsumer messageBodyReceiverConsumer);

       if (!isMessageBodyReceiverConsumerExist)
       {
           var messageBodyReceiverConsumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_messageBodyReceiverChannel);
           messageBodyReceiverConsumer.Received += (ch, ea) =>
           {
               MessageBody messageBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageBody>(Encoding.Default.GetString(ea.Body));

               if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue("Message Body", out List<MessageBody> cacheMessageBodies))
               {
                   cacheMessageBodies.Add(messageBody);
               }
               else
               {
                   _memoryCache.Set("Message Body",
                       new List<MessageBody> { messageBody });
               }
           };
           _memoryCache.Set("message-body-receiver-consumer", messageBodyReceiverConsumer);
       }

       _messageBodyReceiverChannel.BasicConsume(_configuration.MessageReceiverQueue, false, messageBodyReceiverConsumer);

       await _next(context);
   }
   ```

where `messageBody` comes from RabbitMq

3. In controller I have

   ```
   [Authorize]
   [Route("[controller]")]
   [ApiController]
   public class MessageBodyController : ControllerBase
   {
   private readonly IApplicationService<Dto.MessageBody> _messageBodyPresenter;
   private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

   public MessageBodyController(IApplicationService<Dto.MessageBody> messageBodyPresenter, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
   {
       _messageBodyPresenter = messageBodyPresenter;
       _memoryCache = memoryCache;
   }

   [HttpGet]
   [Route("Stop")]
   public IActionResult Stop()
   {
       ((MessageBodyPresenter)_messageBodyPresenter).Stop();
       return Ok();
   }
   }
   ```

But `_memoryCache` is always empty.

I put a breakpoint in my middleware and confirm that data has been set to the cache.

Do I use memory cache in a wrong way? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your full configuration, I guess one issue could be that you have registered the new middleware after the Mvc middleware.
Your registration should look like this:

```
app.UseMiddleware<RabbitMqConsumerMiddleware>();
app.UseMvc();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here is how I register the middleware  

    ```app.UseMiddleware<RabbitMqConsumerMiddleware>();

    app.UseCors("default")
        .UseAuthentication()
        .UseMvc();```

Comment: Okay that seems fine. Please provide your Autofac registration setup then, since thats most likely where the problem is. @Ben

Comment: I added my Autofac registration setup in my question (a bit too long to put here). Thanks

Also I have another found. If I set a value to memory cache in a controller, I can get it from other classes, such as a service (also registered in Autofac DI) associated with this controller.

Comment: There is missing a `services.AddMvc();` in your "ConfigureServices" method. It that missing or did you just leave it out in the example? @Ben

Comment: Sorry missed it. I have added it. I am using AddMvcCore. @KorsG

Comment: No problem. Please provide your RabbitMqConsumerMiddleware contents then, since a problem could be when the cache item is assigned. @Ben

Comment: I added the functions in RabbitMqConsumerMiddleware, which includes the section where cache item is assigned. Thanks @KorsG

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for when you assigned the cache and when you awaited the delegate, but that looks fine. Last thing to see is your controller contents i'm afraid :-) @Ben

Comment: Thanks a lot, @KorsG. I added the detail of the controller in my question. Please have a look.